# JBoss EAP PolicyContext.getContext returns null

Tags: java, jboss, jaas, jacc

I'm in the process of upgrading from JBoss EAP 6.4 to 7.1 but I am experiencing some technical issues regarding the management of the Subject.

### Some context

My application is an EAR file containing:

- a web module
- several EJB modules bearing stateless session beans (SLSBs)
- an EAR file packaging all the above

Authentication is primitive: the username-password credentials are passed on to one of the SLSBs which in turn calls

```
LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext(group.getLoginContextName(), callbackHandler);
loginContext.login();
```

### The problem

My application occasionally retrieves the Subjects in different points of execution—from my web app, my EJBs, simply anywhere. I usually used to use `Subject.getSubject(...)` but this keeps returning null all the time.

I have been asked to use `PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container")` and it *does* return the authenticated Subject, but ONLY where the `loginContext.login();` is called. The moment I call it from anywhere else (including from a different SLSB instance of the same kind), the Subject is null!

What am I missing??

Comment: I had a similar problem (two years after your question). For me the solution was to enter a security-constraint for the URL in the web.xml